# How to handle popup during executing .exe file

Tags: powershell

I have to execute .exe file and handle custom options in popup and supply key stroke through powershell script. Can anyone help?

Required task steps:

1. Read popup window.
2. Enable a radio button in given 4 options.
3. Supply ok keystroke .

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: What you are looking for is UI Automation. There are multiple tools out there that will help you achieve it. If you want to use Powershell, you can check out https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/desktop-application-ui-automation-with-powershell/ . I have not used them and do not attest to it's success. My experience is limited to AutoIT (https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) tool and it did what I needed.

Comment: What .exe are you actually calling? Most support parameter parsing on call.. Have you tried a basic `/?`?

Comment: @paxz There is one process running on production server. If it gets killed in case the script should bring the process up.  I am using start-process command to execute the exe file. I am looking for the script which can handle the popup after calling .exe file. It should enable a radio button and will enter.

Comment: @RohinSidharth I have tried https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/desktop-application-ui-automation-with-powershell/ . But i am facing issue with importing uiautomation module. Once i downloaded the module, i do not find .dll file to import the module. Can you please suggest where am i going wrong.

Comment: @RohinSidharth Can you share me the way how can i use autoit script for that. I can go with that also.

Comment: Autoit comes with an `SciTE editor` and an `AutoIT window Info` tool. On the Window Info tool, there is a Finder tool that you can drag drop onto the GUI window you are trying to automate. most likely, you can see the various handles, properties and methods which you can manipulate to emulate button clicks and such. I learned to do it from a youtube video. i believe it was this one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuOq6AOQ_gI

Comment: However, like @Paxz said, some exe files also come with `commandline` options like `nslookup.exe` or `mstsc.exe`. You can expose them by doing `mstsc.exe /?` on a command prompt.